# Mismatched double token

Tags: antlr

In ANTLR, I have a `MismatchedTokenException` with the following definition:

```
type : IDENTIFIER ('<' (type (',' type)*) '>')?;
```

And the following test:

```
A<B,C<D>>
```

The exception occurs when parsing the first `>`. ANTLR tries parsing both '>>' at once, and fails.

With a silent whitespace channel, the following test *does* work:

```
A<B,C<D> >
```

In which ANTLR is clearly instructed to treat each token separately.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce that. The parser generated by:

```
grammar T;

type       : IDENTIFIER ('<' (type (',' type)*) '>')?;
IDENTIFIER : 'A'..'Z';
```

parses the input `A<B,C<D>>` (without spaces) into the following parse tree:

[image]

You'll need to provide the grammar that causes this input to produce a `MismatchedTokenException`.

Perhaps you're using ANTLRWorks' interpreter (or  Eclipse's ANTLR-IDE, which uses the same interpreter)? In that case, ***that*** is probably the problem: it's notoriously buggy. Don't use it, but use ANTLRWorks' debugger: it's great (the image posted above comes from the debugger).

> **Lazlo Bonin** wrote:
>
> Got it. I had a << token defined. Quickly, is there a way to priorize token recognition over another?

No, the lexer simply tries to match as much as possible. So if it can create a token matching `<<` (or `>>`), it will do so in favor of two single `<` (or `>`) tokens. Only when two (or more) lexer rules match the same amount of characters, a prioritization is made: the rule defined first will then "win" over the one(s) defined later in the grammar.

Comment: Got it. I had a `>>` token defined. Quickly, is there a way to priorize token recognition over another?